# Prevent mysql query to choose the same rows as concurrent select?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

My situation is as follow:

I have table in mysql which have this rows:  "persons_id","locked","status","locked_by"

Person ID: is id for person, its a uniqe, and key 
Locked: Holds value True or Null
Status: can hold "checked or null"
locked_by: Holds tag for instance that used the data...

My python script is doing:

```
how_many = 10    
# get 10 results to start working with
cursor.execute("SELECT persons_id FROM table WHERE locked IS NULL AND checked IS NULL LIMIT %s", (how_many,))

results = cursor.fetchall()

if len(results) > 0:
    for i in results:
        lock_list.append(('instance_1', i))
        # retun ids list for further work 
        list.extend(i)

    # lock the selected IDs, I thought execute many would help prevent deadlocks    
    cursor.executemany("UPDATE table SET locked='True', locked_by=%s WHERE domain=%s", lock_list)
    db.commit()
```

But I still notice when some instances chose the same row, not sure how to select for example 10 rows and update them with locked status at once... if thats even possible in Mysql, maybe I'm going at it completely wrong ?

Using MySQLdb in python

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you running this code from concurrent processes, or what?

Comment: yes correct, same code is executed on multiple instances just the locked_by is different name... Each instance ( could be on different server ) takes chunk of data and do stuff with it.. and I want to prevent two or more instances choosing the same row and doing the same work twice or more...

Comment: As instances are not aware one of another, only control you can have is to put locks on table. But if you put locks, then you loose concurrency. So, you need to minimize locks. I suggest you put lock before select, then update needed values asap in single query, then release lock, and then do stuff with selected data.

Comment: Yea I was thinking the same, to switch the order of the SQL to lock it first and than select the locked ones, but would such SQL work: "UPDATE table SET locked='True', locked_by=%s WHERE locked IS NULL AND checked IS NULL LIMIT %s", (instance_1, how_many,)" mostly if the LIMIT would work for UPDATE operation, is my question.

Comment: I think making all the instances aware of each other would probably require another server and all the instances broadcasting "wait I'm using DB" and some kind of queue... I wonder if somebody did something like that before in python... maybe using separate table in DB for that ? just thinking out loud....